# I want arrange my second list of tuples into the first list of another list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to arrange my second list of tuples into the first list of another list of tuples, while the first list of tuples remains based increasing order based on the second item of each tuple:

```
1st = [('H', 7)]
2nd = [('I', 5), ('J', 6)]
```

output

```
1st = [('I', 5), ('H', 7), ('J', 6)]
```

Comment: Please share the code of what you have attempted

Comment: What order do you want?

Comment: @Frank increasing order of the second item in each tuple

Comment: It seems that your output above is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
first = [('H', 7)] 
second = [('I', 5), ('J', 6)]
first = sorted(second + first, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(first)
# [('I', 5), ('J', 6), ('H', 7)]
```